# What is org.xml.sax.SAXException: Scanner State 24 not Recognized?

Tags: java, xml, exception, sax

I am getting the following Exception but unable to find any documentation specific to this exception:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXException: Scanner State 24 not Recognized
       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:271)
       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
       at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:121)
```

Any help or pointers to the right resources would be very helpful.

Comment: Share code snippet and sample xml.

Comment: I'm late to the party, but the error happened for me, when I accidentally copy&pasted a `<!DOCTYPE ...>` into an `<xsl:template...>`. Maybe it helps those, who arrive here by their favourite search engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Exception is produced by the Sun version of the Xerces parser during DOM parsing. Unfortunately, the specific block of code that raises the Exception is hidden (the following is paraphrased from the [JDK 8.0 DOMParser source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/parsers/DOMParser.java#DOMParser.parse%28org.xml.sax.InputSource%29)):

```
public void parse(InputSource inputSource) throws SAXException, IOException
{
    try
    {
        XMLInputSource xmlInputSource = new XMLInputSource(inputSource.getPublicId(), inputSource.getSystemId(), null);
        xmlInputSource.setByteStream(inputSource.getByteStream());
        xmlInputSource.setCharacterStream(inputSource.getCharacterStream());
        xmlInputSource.setEncoding(inputSource.getEncoding());
        parse(xmlInputSource); <-- Original XNIException is thrown in here
    } catch (XMLParseException e) {
        ...
    } catch (XNIException e) { // <-- wrap XNI exceptions as SAX exceptions
        Exception ex = e.getException();
        if (ex == null) { throw new SAXException(e.getMessage()); }
        if (ex instanceof SAXException) { throw (SAXException) ex; }
        if (ex instanceof IOException) { throw (IOException) ex; }
        throw new SAXException(ex); // <-- Note: The original stack trace is lost here.
    }
}
```

Since the original stack trace is obscured, there are really only two approaches to determining the actual cause of this type of parse Exception:

1. Attach a debugger to the `DOMParser.parse()` method and step through the code to see where the Exception is originally thrown.
2. Remove elements from your XML document until the parse error no longer occurs, then add them back in small increments to determine which element/attribute/processing instruction/etc is triggering the parser error.

If you are not interested in finding the source of the error and are simply trying to make the error go away, you could try using a different XML parser (e.g., a recent version of Apache Xerces instead of the default Sun Xerces parser).

As earlier commenters suggested, supplying a copy of your XML document as well as the specific version of Java (e.g., JDK 8.0u40b25) would enable a more precise answer.